# iOS image resolution issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

In My project I am using image view which downloads image from server. It is working fine on iOS 4 but it is not showing on iOS 5.

Is there any minimum resolution needs to be take care while using iOS 5. One of image which comes from server is of 72 dpi resolution which works on iOS 4 but not on iOS 5.

I have written category to image view which will download code from image URL
Here is code snippet:

```
- (void) setImageFromServer:(NSString *) imageURL 
{
    if (imageURL!=nil) 
    {
        ImageDownloader *imageDownloader = [[[ImageDownloader alloc] init] autorelease];
        imageDownloader.requester = self;
        [imageDownloader startDownload:imageURL]; 
    }
}


- (void) didDownloadImageData:(NSData *) data forImageURL:(NSString *) imageURL 
{
    [self setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];
}
```

In downloader file :

```
- (void) startDownload:(NSString *)MyimageURL {

    self.imageData = [NSMutableData data];
    self.currentImageURL = MyimageURL;

    self.downloadConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.currentImageURL]]
                                                            delegate: self];
    [self.downloadConnection start];
}



- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [imageData appendData:data];
}

- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    [self.requester didDownloadImageData:self.imageData forImageURL:self.currentImageURL];
    isRewardTagImageAvailable = YES;
    [connection release];
    connection = nil;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{

}
```

Comment: Would help if you shared some code - there should really be no difference between displaying images in iOS5 or iOS4

Comment: are you new to iphone development? There appears to be inconsistant use of memory managment terms (i.e. autorelease etc) are you using ARC or manually managing memory?

Comment: @Gaz_Edge Yes i have manually managed memory.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is a problem, but usually when I am writing a NSURLRequest I first initialize things as follows and the insert the request into a NSURLConnection. Sort of like this. Also note that once you initWithRequst in a NSURLConnection, you do not have to tell that connection to start, it will automatically.

```
NSURLRequest *tempReq = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:someURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData  timeoutInterval:10.0];
NSURLConnection *tempCon = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:tempReq delegate:self];
```

I mean it should not matter, but give that a shot because looking at your, code it looks fine.

I would recommend adding the didFailWithError method:

```
-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error;
```

To your files as well because maybe your connection is failing for some reason as well.

Comment: I tested my code on iOS 5.0 its working fine but not on iOS 5.0.1. Is there any API/ image dpi problem?

Comment: There should not be no. I grab images all of the time using a similar proces, and have not really had any problems. The problem I usually have though is forgetting to allocate memory for an array or NSMutableData. Other than that maybe you are losing something when trying to pass it between classes.

Comment: I have created an example project doing what you are trying to do, and I had no problem grabbing an image from the internet and passing it out to a UIImageView. I can send it to you if you want.

Comment: @All Thanks. The issue get solved when I reset device having iOS 5.0.1 . Now images from server are visible. I dont know the reason behind this.

Answer (score 0):

Is your connection synchronous or async ?

If async, you shouldn't autorelease your ImageDownloader, because there are some chance that it would be released for the connectionDidFinishLoading message.

Try to alloc your ImageDownloader normally, then release it when it finishes the download (both in *connectionDidFinishLoading* and *didFailWithError*)